# Easy way to get wiktionary titles only in one language?

Tags: mediawiki-api, wiktionary

I can get easily a [dump](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz) with all the titles in the wiktionary, but this dump contains every word, even non-English ones.

For example, you find `souris` (`mouse`in French): https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/souris

Is there an easy way or an existing script to get *only* the titles in one *specific* language. I would like to get all the English words from the wiktionary, excluding the ones which do not exist in this language.

So far my only idea is to parse the text and check if there is a `==English==` line, but it is too slow to be usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll need to either:

- parse the already existing list of [english words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:English) in the wiktionary, which were extracted from a database dump.
- download the database dump (and not only the titles) and extract the terms yourself.

I tried option a) only because option b) would imply a several GB download.
It's very simple, in fact I include a quick JS implementation that you can use as a base to create your own script in your preferred language.

```
var baseURL="http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:English/"
var letters=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for(i=0;i<letters.length;i++) {
    var letter = letters[i];
    console.log(letter);
    $.get(baseURL+letter, function(response) { 
        $(response).find('ol li a').each( function (k,v) { console.log(v.text) })    
    })
}
```

**EDIT**
I was quite curious on the subject myself, so I wrote a python script. Just in case somebody finds it useful:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from lxml.html import fromstring
import urllib2

url = 'http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:English/'
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
for l in letters:
    req = urllib2.Request(url+l, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
    con = urllib2.urlopen( req )
    response = con.read()
    h = fromstring(response)
    sel = CSSSelector("ol li a")

    for x in sel(h):
        print x.text.encode('utf-8')
```

I'd paste the results to pastebin myself but the 500kb limit won't let me

Comment: It looks like that page (`Index:English`) is gone now. Similar data remains available at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_lemmas . That page is paginated, though, so scraping it will require code a little more complex than the scripts in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution and code samples serans posted were great, but I had trouble getting his python code to run.

I followed his example and wrote a ruby version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require "rexml/document"

url = 'http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:English/'

('a'..'z').to_a.each do |letter|
  response = Net::HTTP.get(URI(url + letter))
  doc = REXML::Document.new(response)
  REXML::XPath.each(doc, "//ol/li/a") do |element|
    puts element.text
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Following from @serans' answer, I've created a GitHub Gist to do the same in Swift

https://gist.github.com/ashleymills/549ab8aff05ec90f4350#file-wiktionaryfetcher-swift